# Is it possible to divide a Array in VBA

Tags: arrays, vba, search, binary, split

Is it possible to divide an Array?

Example:

```
array(2) As String
array(1) = "test1"
array(2) = "test2"

~ Now Split

array1 (contains test1) & array 2 (contains test2)
```

I want to implement a Binarysearch

Comment: You'd have to write a method to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can split like this

```
Sub split_array()

Dim array1(1 To 2) As String
Dim array2(1 To 2) As String
Dim array3(1 To 2) As String

array1(1) = "Test1"
array1(2) = "Test2"

array2(1) = array1(1)
array3(1) = array1(2)

End Sub
```

But I suspect that is not the best way to do it. I think you would do much better using 3 (probably long integer) variables to represent positions in the array. 1 to represent the 1st element, 1 to represent the last element and 1 to represent the mid element.

```
Dim lLowerSearchElement As Long
Dim lUpperSearchElement As Long
Dim lMiddleSearchElement As Long
Dim array1(1 to 999) as string

lLowerSearchElement = 1
lUpperSearchElement = 999
lMiddleSearchElement = (lUpperSearchElement + lLowerSearchElement) / 2
```

You can then check if the if the element is equal to, greater or less then the middle element and proceed accordingly.

Also remember that you will need to sort your data before attempting to use a binary search and it would be useful if you know about recursive calling.

You also need to test your implementation rigorously as a small mistake could result in the search not working probably.

Edit 22/08/13

The implementation I use for a binary search is given below:

```
Function bCheckSamplePoint(ByRef lSamplePointArray() As String, ByRef bfound As Boolean, _
    ByVal lSamplePoint As String) As Boolean
    'byref used for the array as could be slow to keep copying the array, bFound is used by calling procedure

    Dim lLowerSearchElement As Long
    Dim lUpperSearchElement As Long
    Dim lMiddleSearchElement As Long

    bfound = False 'False until found

    'Set initial limits of the search
    lLowerSearchElement = 0
    lUpperSearchElement = UBound(lSamplePointArray())

    Do While lLowerSearchElement <= lUpperSearchElement And bfound = False
        lMiddleSearchElement = (lUpperSearchElement + lLowerSearchElement) / 2
        If StrComp(lSamplePointArray(lMiddleSearchElement), lSamplePoint, vbTextCompare) = -1 Then
'            'Must be greater than middle element
            lLowerSearchElement = lMiddleSearchElement + 1
        ElseIf (lSamplePointArray(lMiddleSearchElement) = lSamplePoint) Then
            bfound = True
        Else
            'must be lower than middle element
            lUpperSearchElement = lMiddleSearchElement - 1
        End If 'lSamplePointArray(lmiddlesearchlelemnt) < lSamplePoint

    Loop 'While lLowerSearchElement <= lUpperSearchElement

ErrorExit:
    bCheckSamplePoint = bReturn
    Exit Function
```

As you can see this binary search is only checking to see wether a string is found in an array of strings, but it could be modified for other purposes.

Comment: Usually I'm coding in Java, and there is the split function directly in the memory. As I'm understanding your answer, I should use a loop to copy the array. But in my opinion this is not an time-saving way to do it. You'll lose the general thoughts behind the binary search. Or did I misunderstood you?

Comment: The idea behind my answer is that you don't really do anything to the array, you change the value of the long integers that point to positions in your array so using the example of 1000 elelment array if the value you are looking for is less than the middle search element you set the upper search element to the middle element -1 and start again. I will edit my text to show you the implementation I use.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a split function to do binary search

My VBA version of binary search can be found at
http://fastexcel.wordpress.com/2011/08/02/developing-faster-lookups-part-3-a-binary-search-udf/

Comment: Can you please explain me, why the LookupArray is 2-dimensional?

Comment: Because if you get values from a range into a variant the result is a 2-dimensional array even if the range is a single column.

Answer (score 0):

Split Array into chunks

```
Public Function splitArray(ByVal initial_array As Variant, Optional chunk_size As Long = 1) As Variant()
  Dim split_array() As Variant
  Dim chunk() As Variant
  Dim chunk_index As Integer: chunk_index = 0
  Dim array_index As Integer: array_index = 1

  If UBound(initial_array) > chunk_size Then
    For i = 0 To UBound(initial_array)
      If (i + 1) / (chunk_size * array_index) = 1 Or i = UBound(initial_array) Then
        ReDim Preserve chunk(chunk_index)
        chunk(chunk_index) = initial_array(i)
        ReDim Preserve split_array(array_index - 1)
        split_array(array_index - 1) = chunk
        chunk_index = 0
        array_index = array_index + 1
      Else
        ReDim Preserve chunk(chunk_index)
        chunk(chunk_index) = initial_array(i)
        chunk_index = chunk_index + 1
      End If
    Next i
    splitArray = split_array
  Else
    ReDim Preserve split_array(0)
    split_array(0) = initial_array
    splitArray = split_array
  End If

End Function
```